# ActiveMQ: how can one define permissions per queue/topic?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am setting up a Message Queuing service for our environment based on Apache ActiveMQ. For that I am trying to find information on how one can define access rights per queue, or per topic, resp.

With the default mechanism I am able to define new users and passwords but apparently with this then ALL users have access to ALL queues/topics (which may be OK for other use-cases but not here).

In a former JMS setup that I had worked with (Tibco EMS) one was able to define queue access rights (and corresponding credentials) on a per queue basis. I have not found any description or instructions on how to do that with ActiveMQ. Any hints or pointers anyone?

Note: I am talking about the programmatic queue/topic access (from Java clients) to the ActiveMQ server here, not the admin's Web-Console.

Comment: If you're starting a *new* project I'd recommend using [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/), the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ. You can find documentation about security configuration [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html).

Comment: Did you read [the security documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/security.html) for ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Comment: Sorry for the lazy reply. Yes, I had read it but it hadn't made sense to me during the first read. I re-read and now I am starting to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add authorization.

Features:

- Permission per-queue exact name match (ie QUOTE.INPUT)
- Permission by *namespace* (ie ORDER.> all queues that start with the prefix)
- Permissions include *read*, *write* and *admin* (ability to auto-create destinations by sending or reading)

```
<broker...> 
  .. 
    <plugins> 
      .. 
      <authorizationPlugin> 
        <map> 
          <authorizationMap> 
            <authorizationEntries> 
              <authorizationEntry queue="QUOTE.INPUT" read="quote-group,admin-role" write="quote-role,admin-role" admin="quote-role,admin-role" /> 
              <authorizationEntry queue="ORDER.>" read="order-group,admin-role" write="order-role,admin-role" admin="order-role,admin-role" /> 
              <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="*" write="*" admin="*"/> 
            </authorizationEntries> 
            <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry> 
              <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry read="admin-role" write="admin-role" admin="admin-role"/> 
            </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry> 
          </authorizationMap> 
        </map> 
      </authorizationPlugin> 
      .. 
    </plugins> 
  .. 
</broker>
```

Comment: This is close to what I had in mind. I hadn't realized that on the first read of the doc. Combining this with the users and groups/roles as defined in users.properties and    groups.properties (see ref above by Justin Bertram) it all started to make sense. Thanks!